# Prevent SVG background bleed for icon?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

The goal is to prevent background bleed of SVG icons so they can appear as standalone files. Many answers to similar questions suggest putting a DIV or other container around the SVG element to prevent bleed, but the goal is to make the SVG icon stand alone without any dependency on a container.

Prepending a `rect` element to act as a background element doesn't work reliably as this method breaks for certain viewport aspect ratios.

Is this possible?

Note: to see the flaw, you must download and open the SVG file in the browser. Using JSFiddle/CodePen hides the problem because those sites encapsulate the SVG in a container (which fixes the bleed issue).

Download SVG here: https://gofile.io/?c=eKzjk7

Example SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="rgb(255, 120, 50)" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 102); border-radius: 0%">
    
    <path d="M8 11.5c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5S5 10.67 5 11.5 5.67 13 6.5 13 8 12.33 8 11.5zm7-5c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5h-3C9.67 5 9 5.67 9 6.5S9.67 8 10.5 8h3c.83 0 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5zM8.5 15c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5S7.67 18 8.5 18s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5S9.33 15 8.5 15zM12 1C5.93 1 1 5.93 1 12s4.93 11 11 11 11-4.93 11-11S18.07 1 12 1zm0 20c-4.96 0-9-4.04-9-9s4.04-9 9-9 9 4.04 9 9-4.04 9-9 9zm5.5-11c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5s.67 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm-2 5c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5s.67 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5z"/>
    
    </svg>
```

Ideal output:

[image]

Actual output:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code of how you are using the SVG as background?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] where it fails. The `<svg>` you posted behaves like the [desired output](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/p6k5efLy/).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu sure, one second.

Comment: @TemaniAfif definitely! thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no bleed issue.You'd have the same problem if the background image was a an image file as well. You need to specify, via CSS, how you want the `backgroundImage` to behave, and you do that with [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: are you consierng the correct doctype on your file? because jsfiddle doens't add container

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you don't see a bleed if you download the SVG file and open it standalone in a browser?

Comment: @TemaniAfif were you able to download the file and open it standalone in the browser without seeing any bleeding?

Comment: @Crashalot, who cares how the browser chooses to render an `<svg>` when the `<svg>` is ***the document***? There is no standard on how it should render, which is why it might change tomorrow, if some browser's dev team decides it should. However, you have total control over how it renders when it's inserted in another document, which is how everyone else uses `<svg>`s.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu sorry for the confusion. this is relevant because users use these SVG file as icons, and when you download the file and view it from the desktop/operating system, the image preview shows the bleed and thus leads users to think the icon itself bleeds.

Comment: Afaik, you can't control this from inside the `<svg>`. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu ok please post as an answer if this is the case

Answer (score 2):

Use a gradient and disable the repeat to avoid this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="rgb(255, 120, 50)" style="background:linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 102),rgb(255, 255, 102)) no-repeat ; border-radius: 0%">
    
    <path d="M8 11.5c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5S5 10.67 5 11.5 5.67 13 6.5 13 8 12.33 8 11.5zm7-5c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5h-3C9.67 5 9 5.67 9 6.5S9.67 8 10.5 8h3c.83 0 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5zM8.5 15c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5S7.67 18 8.5 18s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5S9.33 15 8.5 15zM12 1C5.93 1 1 5.93 1 12s4.93 11 11 11 11-4.93 11-11S18.07 1 12 1zm0 20c-4.96 0-9-4.04-9-9s4.04-9 9-9 9 4.04 9 9-4.04 9-9 9zm5.5-11c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5s.67 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm-2 5c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5s.67 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5z"/>
    
    </svg>
```

I don't know exactly how to explain this but it behaves the same as background propagation from `html` to canvas

Example of the issue

```css
html {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Fixed with gradient

```css
html {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) no-repeat;
}
```

Since there is a propagation, `border-radius` won't have any effect so an idea would be to use a `radial-gradient`:

```css
html {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 97%,transparent 100%) no-repeat;
}
```

In case you want any kind of `border-radius` here is another idea with more background layers:

```css
html {
  --r:25px; /* adjust this to control the Radius (Max value = width/2) */
  --c:red;
  
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) top     right /var(--r) var(--r),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) bottom  left  /var(--r) var(--r),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left ,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) bottom  right /var(--r) var(--r),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) top     left  /var(--r) var(--r),
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--r)) 100%,
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) center/100% calc(100% - 2*var(--r)) ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

For a non rectangular icon:

```css
html {
  --rx:40px; /* adjust this to control the X Radius (Max value = width/2) */ 
  --ry:75px; /* adjust this to control the Y Radius (Max value = height/2) */
 
  --c:red;
  
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) top     right /var(--rx) var(--ry),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) bottom  left  /var(--rx) var(--ry),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left ,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) bottom  right /var(--rx) var(--ry),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) top     left  /var(--rx) var(--ry),
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--rx)) 100%,
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) center/100% calc(100% - 2*var(--ry)) ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

And more fancy if you want to also simulate `background-clip`/`background-origin`

```css
html {
  --p:15px;  /* offset from the edges*/
  --rx:35px; /* Max value = width/2 - var(--p)*/
  --ry:25px; /* Max value = height/2 - var(--p)*/
  --c:red;
  
  width:120px;
  height:100px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) top var(--p)    right var(--p)/var(--rx) var(--ry),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) bottom var(--p) left  var(--p)/var(--rx) var(--ry),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left ,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) bottom var(--p) right var(--p)/var(--rx) var(--ry),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,var(--c) 97%,transparent 100%) top var(--p)   left  var(--p) /var(--rx) var(--ry),
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) center/calc(100% - 2*(var(--p) + var(--rx))) calc(100% - 2*var(--p)),
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--p)) calc(100% - 2*(var(--p) + var(--ry))) ;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: wow, creative. what if we also want to enable a border-radius on the background? in the example it's set at 0% but assume a border-radius of 50%.

Comment: @Crashalot yes border-radius would be tricky but if it's only 50% I can add a radial-gradient instead (will update)

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't reproduce the problem you have. When I insert that `svg` everything is fine for me. Yellow background is only as big as circle. Would be good if you could provide CodePen or JSFiddle with your problem..

Here is what you can do.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="rgb(255, 120, 50)" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 102); border-radius: 0%; width: auto; height: auto;">

<path d="M8 11.5c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5S5 10.67 5 11.5 5.67 13 6.5 13 8 12.33 8 11.5zm7-5c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5h-3C9.67 5 9 5.67 9 6.5S9.67 8 10.5 8h3c.83 0 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5zM8.5 15c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5S7.67 18 8.5 18s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5S9.33 15 8.5 15zM12 1C5.93 1 1 5.93 1 12s4.93 11 11 11 11-4.93 11-11S18.07 1 12 1zm0 20c-4.96 0-9-4.04-9-9s4.04-9 9-9 9 4.04 9 9-4.04 9-9 9zm5.5-11c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5s.67 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm-2 5c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5s.67 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5z"/>

</svg>
```

Note that I aded

```css
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

This will make background as big as svg. If this is not what you were looking for write a comment so we can resolve a problem.

Comment: updated the question, thanks for your help! not sure why you're getting downvoted for a good faith answer.