# SVG: how to round stroke and rectangle corners?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to round a rectangle in SVG while ensuring the stroke obeys the roundedness of corners? The code below isn't working.

**No Stroke:**

`stroke-width="0px"`

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="0px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

**With Stroke:**

`stroke-width="10px"`

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

The stroke seems to follow the original sharp corners instead of the rounded corners.

Comment: add `overflow:visible` to the svg and you will understand what is happening (half inside and half outside)

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you suggest for enforcing a border on a rounded rectangle?

Comment: Why are you rounding an svg instead of a div?

Comment: @NathanielFlick the `rect` element acts a background element for an icon. ideally, we can use pure SVG so users can choose to download in SVG or raster format.

Answer (score 12):

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

A wide string extends beyond the svg border of the canvas SVG. Therefore, the string is partially cropped.

[image]

You must reduce the size of the rectangle so that the line is visible and shift  the upper left corner of the rectangle right and down `x="5"` and `y="5"`

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="5" y="5" width="90" height="90" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

**Update**

ViewBox added. The coordinates of the rectangle `x` and`y` of the  are increased, SVG wrapped in a container and can be embedded in an HTML page as a separate block. **Adaptive application**

```css
.container {
width:30%;
height:30%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 110 110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="90" height="90" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see from the picture, a square with a wide stroke is completely inside the SVG canvas

Comment: This would work, except it seems the stroke is not consistently rendered across browsers. In some browsers, it seems rendered in the center of the element border and some browsers it's fully inside? Details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241393/can-you-control-how-an-svgs-stroke-width-is-drawn

Comment: @Crashalot  Stroke svg elements are always displayed symmetrically relative to the border of the elements. With a stroke width of 10 pixels - 5px outside the element 5px inside the element. In the snippet, my example works in Chrome Firefox. If the stroke is incorrect in other browsers, then try to enlarge the viewport and increase the initial coordinates of the rectangle ` x` and `y`

Comment: I think the challenge here is to have an adaptative rectangle inside the SVG. In both of your examples you are either fixing the width/height of the rect or the ratio so yes it's adaptative but always remain a square. We cannot have something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/9cd62hy5/1/ where the rect is always 100% in width/height of the SVG. I found a solution using calc() here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496341/8620333 but it works find only on Chrome. (PS: the use of height in the second case is useless since the parent has no defined height)

Comment: @Temani Afif I answered the question OP  `Is it possible to round a rectangle in SVG while ensuring the stroke obeys the roundedness of corners?` And I explained in the first example why the round stroke is not visible, since it did not fit completely on the SVG canvas. The second example is given as a bonus on how to make a rectangle or any other shape adaptive in SVG. Namely: add the `viewBox` and remove the fixed width / height in the header of the SVG file. I always carefully study your creative answers to questions from the participants of this site. I really like many of your answers.

Comment: You are entirely answering the question but I think the OP missed some details because I am pretty sure this one is asked due to the issue faced in his old one here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58784579/8620333 where I suggested to him to turn out to SVG since the CSS solution is a bit hacky that's why I think the responsive part (not clearly asked here) is important and that's why he's using 100% in height/width. I added an answer as I noticed firefox fixed the issue with calc() so it should be a good solution (don't know about the other browser)[thanks for the compliment btw]

Answer (score 4):

The first trivial solution is to make the overflow visible and add some margin to rectify this

```css
svg {
  overflow:visible;
  margin:5px; /*half the stroke*/
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>

<svg width="150" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

Or you use `calc()` like below:

```css
svg rect{
  height:calc(100% - 10px);
  width:calc(100% - 10px);
  x:5px;
  y:5px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>

<svg width="150" height="80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="10px" rx="10px" ry="10px" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

That can be used as background too:

```css
.box {
    background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  ><rect x="5" y="5" width="100%" height="100%" style="height:calc(100% - 10px);width:calc(100% - 10px)" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" rx="10" ry="10" stroke-linejoin="round" /></svg>');
    color: #fff;
    padding:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 75px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> Some text here</div>

<div class="box"> text very loooooooooooong here</div>


<div class="box"> a text <br> two line here</div>
```

Comment: why do you define the width/height in the svg markup, but also use css style rules to define the size? won't the inline size overrule the css size?

Comment: @Crashalot no, the CSS one will override because it's width/height attribute and not inline width/height so the CSS is more specific than it and you can simply remove the attribute one. You don't have to define them, I simply kept the same SVG from the first to the second snippet

Comment: @Crashalot related question to understand why the CSS override the attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56727105/8620333

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg width="400" height="180">
    <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150"
          style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
</svg>
```